# Publish precompiled-X binaries locally for SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to build SBT locally and use the snapshot version.

The [development docs](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/CONTRIBUTING.md) suggest that all that's required is to publish locally with

`sbt publishLocal`

And to then update the sbt batch file to point at the updated loader jar.

This does not work however when starting sbt due to unresolved dependencies eg

`unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_8_2;0.13.8-SNAPSHOT: not found`

This is not surprising as, examining the local ivy cache, no precompiled-XXX binaries are generated by publishLocal.

Are the docs incorrect or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a bug in our CONTRIBUTING file. Try:

```
sbt release-sbt-local
```

Comment: Unfortunately still can't see any precompiled-X in .ivy2/local

Comment: There's an open pull request on the build fix that I submitted recently. Could you try `wip/build-fix` branch? It no longer uses the precompiled stuff.

Comment: I merged it to 0.13, so grab the latest actually.